# TextView get wrong width value after set LayoutParam width

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm trying to set TextView width, and I use LayoutParam to set view width, but after I setLayoutParam on TextView then print it's width, it return different value to the value I set.

here is logs and code:

[logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlVGO.png)

```
public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    colYear = itemView.findViewById(R.id.colYear);
    colAge = itemView.findViewById(R.id.colAge);
    colMoney = itemView.findViewById(R.id.colMoney);

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams yearParam = colYear.getLayoutParams();
    yearParam.width = firstColWidth;
    colYear.setLayoutParams(yearParam);

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams ageParam = colAge.getLayoutParams();
    ageParam.width = secondColWidth;
    colAge.setLayoutParams(ageParam);
    Log.d("Adapter","firstColWidth:"+firstColWidth);
    Log.d("Adapter","secondColWidth:"+secondColWidth);
    colYear.post(()->Log.d("Adapter","colYear:"+colYear.getWidth()));
    colAge.post(()->Log.d("Adapter","colAge:"+colAge.getWidth()));
}
```

I also try to use `TextView.setWidth()` directly, but still has same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, I use a LinearLayout contain TextView and each TextView has default layout_weight, remove layout_weight then work fine.